# I have set the html checkbox the checked property to false,but it still checked

Tags: input, checkbox

here is my html markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="false">
```

I have set the `checked` to false, but the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/CK6ve/) is still checked

Why this happened? If I remove the checked property, it would turn unchecked.

Actually I want insert a `input[type=checkbox]` into html markup in dynamic, with parameter to determine checked or not

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you specify checked, then it is checked; it doesn't matter if you say checked="false", checked="true", checked="checked" or just plain checked.

If you don't want it checked, then do not include the checked attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked