# How to add attribute checkbox (checked=true) in array by javarscript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add attribute checked=true with multiple inputs like this:

```
<form id="students" method="post">
                  <div class="row">
                      <input id="aa" name="a[]" value="Smith" type="text" class="a1" >
                      <input id="bb" name="b[]" value="Alen" type="text" class="b1" >
                      <input id="save" name="save[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="ab" disabled="disabled" >
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <input id="aa" name="a[]" value="" type="text" class="a1"  >
                      <input id="bb" name="b[]" value="" type="text" class="b1" >
                      <input id="save" name="save[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="ab"  >
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <input id="aa" name="a[]" value="Bill" type="text" class="a1"   >
                      <input id="bb" name="b[]" value="Mark" type="text" class="b1" >
                      <input id="save" name="save[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="ab" >
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <input id="aa" name="a[]" value="" type="text" class="a1"  >
                      <input id="bb" name="b[]" value="" type="text" class="b1" >
                      <input id="save" name="save[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="ab" >
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <input id="aa" name="a[]" value="Kell" type="text" class="a1"  >
                      <input id="bb" name="b[]" value="Keith" type="text" class="b1" >
                      <input id="save" name="save[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="ab" >
                  </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitbutton" class="insert" onclick="checkform()"/>
</form>
```

And each line input has no value I add attribute checked=false of checkbox. How I do. Who can help me? thanks.

This is javaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkform() {
   var myForm = document.forms.students;
   var myControls = myForm.elements['a[]'];
   for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) {
    if(myControls[i].value==""){
        $(".ab").attr("checked", true); //check input had value then 
        }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing a `.` in this line  `$(".ab")attr("checked", true);` It should rather be `$(".ab").attr("checked", true);`

Comment: ah. Sorry. I put up is not enough

Comment: @HTT **Do not use an id on more than one element** A duplicated id will cause unexpected behavior. You have 5 sets of  `id='aa'`, `id='bb'`, and `id='save'`. Change them to a class or place a unique number or letter on their ids

Comment: Are you checking only inputs that are `name="a[]"`? or do want to check `name="b[]"` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your question says: "... I add attribute checked=false..."

But your code says:

```
$(".ab").attr("checked",true); //not false like the question says
```

Please tell me that's not it ;)

Comment: What I mean is when I press the submit, then check if the line is going to have value add attr("checked",true). otherwise add attr("checked",false)

Comment: Have you tried prop instead of attr? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: The checked property is a bit special. If a checkbox has it, the checkbox is checked. Setting it to false has no effect. If you want an unchecked checkbox, the property should not be added to it. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907454/i-have-set-the-html-checkbox-the-checked-property-to-false-but-it-still-checked

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o20Lvvm2/4/).

You can swap them around if I misunderstood and you want inputs with something in them to be checked and not vice versa.

In the fiddle I changed it so that the button click is handled by jquery instead of the onClick() attribute of the input.

```
function checkform() {
   var myForm = document.forms.students;
   $(myForm).find('input[name="a[]"], input[name="b[]"]').filter(function(){
        if(!$.trim(this.value)){
            $(this).siblings('.ab').prop('checked', true)
        }else{
            $(this).siblings('.ab').prop('checked', false)
        }
   });
 }
```

I also updated it to check both a[] and b[].

Additionally, I removed the myControls variable since you don't need it here.

Comment: great. You are clever. Thanks

Comment: No problem, accept the answer though so I get my rep up!! lol