# How to check checkbox from cfquery results

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a case where I need to check a checkbox based on a `cfquery` result. The database will return `1 or 0` which I thought would make it pretty simple to handle from there, but I am unsure of how to represent that data into a HTML checkbox.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<cfquery name="ContainsSic" datasource="#Application.PrimaryDataSource#">
    SELECT HasSiC
    FROM tblAssayResults
    WHERE CustomerID = 838
    AND LotNumber = 15
    AND SubLot = 1
</cfquery>          

    <cfset SicResults = ContainsSic.HasSiC>

<cfoutput>
    <tr>
     <td align="center">#Passed_CustomerName#</td>
     <td align="center">#Passed_LotNumber#</td>
     <td align="center">#Passed_SubLot#</td>
     <td align="center">#Passed_CarbonAvg#</td>
     <td align="center"><input type="button" onclick="" value="Amend" /></td>
     <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="#SicResults#"/></td>
     <td align="center"></td>
     <td align="center"><input type="button" onclick=""/></td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Basically if I didn't explain correctly, if the database returns a 1 the checkbox should show the checkbox as checked of course and so on. I should mention that everything is within a `cfloop` which will probably be apart of a separate question later on.

I currently only get empty checkboxes even though the database returns a `1`. Do I need to include a `cfif` and make the `1` return as `true`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with the solution by **madeyejm**: It will either return `checked="false"` or `checked="true"` -- but the mere *presence* of the `checked` attribute (regardless of its value) will cause the box to be checked.

I think the following is in line with what you need.

```
<cfset SicResults = ContainsSic.HasSiC>
<cfif ContainsSic.HasSiC EQ 1 >
    <cfset CheckedResult = "checked=""checked""" >
<cfelse>
    <cfset CheckedResult = "" >
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
    <tr>
     <td align="center">#Passed_CustomerName#</td>
     <td align="center">#Passed_LotNumber#</td>
     <td align="center">#Passed_SubLot#</td>
     <td align="center">#Passed_CarbonAvg#</td>
     <td align="center"><input type="button" onclick="" value="Amend" /></td>
     <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="#SicResults#" #CheckedResult#/></td>
     <td align="center"></td>
     <td align="center"><input type="button" onclick=""/></td>
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Joe, I added some code in the OP, do you think this is a decent route to go? Or could there be potential issues within the future?

Comment: I don't think you're quite there yet: Your solution populates the `value` of the checkbox -- but this is only the value when the form is submitted. It doesn't affect whether the box is checked at page load or not. And if you used your new variable in the `checked` field, you'd face the same issue as in the code by **madeyejm**: Sometimes the value would be `checked="false"` -- but it would still appear because the browser is only looking for the `checked` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the extra input. I completely missed that. Not as sharp in the morning haha.

Comment: Oh okay I got it. Thank you for your input. I'm glad I asked for clarification. Sorry @madeyejm I had to accept this as the better answer. I appreciate your's and Joe's input. Cheers

Comment: No worries! Happy to have contributed even if just a little.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd pick the first post I saw today and try to help someone in need...

Don't know much on CF, but I've worked with JSTL, the standard JSP tag library. In that taglib there is a foreach tag which allows you to loop over any enumerable output or JSP variables.

1. Quick check... Have you tried setting the `checked` attribute on the checkbox?
2. More in-depth thought...

I'm wondering can you apply something like that here using a cfloop? Because I think the cfquery tag returns an enumerable data structure that would need iterated through to account for all the records returned in the query result.

Here's my pseudo-code...

```
<!-- run your query -->
<cfset SicResults = ContainsSic>    
<cfset checkedValue = false>

<cfloop from="0" to="SicResults.recordCount" index="i">
  //not sure on cf tags to complete following...
  if ContainsSic[i].HasSiC === 1
    checkedValue = true
  <cfoutput>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">#Passed_CustomerName#</td>
      <td align="center">#Passed_LotNumber#</td>
      <td align="center">#Passed_SubLot#</td>
      <td align="center">#Passed_CarbonAvg#</td>
      <td align="center"><input type="button" onclick="" value="Amend" /></td> 
      <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" checked="#checkedValue#"/></td>
      <td align="center"></td>
      <td align="center"><input type="button" onclick=""/></td>
    </tr>
  </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I think both answers will work, but this will probably make more sense and cause less errors. Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Interested to see how things go. Ternary statements like the one Ilya suggested are good too, but admittedly I'm not aware of CF's support for those types of conditional statements.

Comment: They do, but the problem is that I am using data that's not technically there because I am using an outdated database for testing so Ilya's answer threw up some errors. The edited OP I shared is basically going your route. Thank you again for your help

Comment: This answer will not work. `checked="false"` will still leave the checkbox checked. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10907476/923833)

Comment: Ah good call. I guess you could move the if into the table cell that renders the checkbox and if the condition is true, render a checkbox input with the checked attribute, else render a checkbox input excluding the checked attribute

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="#SicResults#" #((SicResults) ? "checked='checked'" : "")# /></td>
```

Comment: I think you wanted `checked="#SicResults...` instead of `value=`